# Apex Controller Using in VisualForce in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
Blob firstNameBlob = Encodingutil.base64Decode(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('firstName'));
firstName = firstNameBlob.toString();
```

Iam using in my ApexController Page . Please Explain Above two lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line takes the encoded URL parameter 'firstName', decodes it and puts it in the Blob variable 'firstNameBlob'.
The second line converts it into a String and stores it in a variable called firstName.